# How improve Javascript code checking in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have enabled Javascript validation in Visual Studio Code, but it's not clear to me how to improve/configure this validation...

VS Code User Settings

```
"javascript.validate.enable": true,
"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true,
```

Now I get errors for unknown types:

```
TweenMax.to(elem,1,{})
```

> cannot find name "TweenMax"

I have tried adding the [tweenmax.d.ts typings file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/gsap/Tween.d.ts) in the project but that has no effect.

I also get errors when an element is too generic, but I don't know how to fix this:

```
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName("mybtn")[0]
btn.style.color = "#FFF"
```

> Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.

In typescript you can use `as` to tell the IDE what type of element this is:

```
let btn = btns[0] as HTMLDivElement
btn.style.color = "#FFF"              // now this is allowed
```

How do I solve these errors in Javascript? Should I use [a jsconfig file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)? But how?

Comment: I don't know what is TweenMax.
About style property, 'getElementByClassName' retrieves an array of html objects not an html object, so try btn[0].style.color.

Comment: I did that already :) You can see `[0]` after `getElementsByClassName("mybtn")[0]`

Comment: Have you tested with "// @ts-check" to the top of the file?

Comment: Yes but the error is correct: Element doesn’t have a style property. I just don’t know how to fix this in Javascript